# Gulp.src: компиляция SASS ошибка readdir

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-2015, sass

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь скомпилировать SASS (точнее, SCSS) планировщиком Gulp. Использую Node.JS tools for Visual Studio Community 2015.

Gulpfile.js имеет следующий вид:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task('sass', function () 
  return gulp.src('css/main.scss')
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('css/main.css'));
});
```

Соответственно, в директории css лежат файлы main.css и main.scss

При запуске (точнее, даже не при запуске задачи, а при открытии самого диспетчера) task runner explorer ("диспетчер выполнения задач") пишет:

```
не удалось выполнить загрузку..
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
fs.js:808
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\К\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Node_Gulp\Node_Gulp\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
```

gulp-sass в проекте установлен

Answer (score 1):

немного шаманства, подробнее см. здесь https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579

решение: npm rebuild node-sass (не gulp-sass, а именно node-sass, одна из dependencies)